# why shallow copy on Hashmap is not reflecting

Tags: java, clone, shallow-copy

I have created the map added few items and clone to demonstrate shallow copy. after cloning I added a new item into old reference but item was not reflected into new reference.

```java
public class Test implements Cloneable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String,String> smap  = new HashMap<String,String>();
        smap.put("a1","a1");
        smap.put("a2","a2");
        smap.put("a3","a3");
        smap.put("a4","a4");

        //SHALLOW COPY 
        HashMap<String,String> cMap = (HashMap)smap.clone();
        cMap.put("b1","bb");


        smap.put("a5","55");

        System.out.println("orignal_map\t"+smap);
        System.out.println("cMap\t"+cMap);

        HashMap<String, String> scopyx = new HashMap<String, String>(smap);
        System.out.println("S_copy_x:\t"+scopyx);

    }
}
```

Comment: They're separate objects. Why would changes to `smap` be reflected in `cMap`?

Comment: The whole point of creating a shallow copy is so that adding/removing from one collection does NOT add/remove from the other

Comment: so in case of collection shallow clone is failing or any other reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shallow copying means that it is not applied to copying objects inside the original objects.  That is, if you have an object containing a collection and you clone this object, the collection itself is not copied and may become shared between multiple instances:

```
public class Test implements Cloneable {
    private List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addBaz(String baz) {
        innerList.add(baz);
    }

    public List<String> getInnerList() {
        return innerList;
    }

    public void setInnerList(List<String> innerList) {
        this.innerList = innerList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        Test bar1 = new Test();
        bar1.addBaz("baz1");
        bar1.addBaz("baz2");
        bar1.addBaz("baz3");

        System.out.println("bar1 before cloning: " + bar1.getInnerList());

        Test cloneBar = (Test) bar1.clone();

        System.out.println("clone: " + cloneBar.getInnerList());

        bar1.addBaz("baz4");
        System.out.println("clone after adding to original: " + cloneBar.getInnerList());

        cloneBar.addBaz("cloneBaz1");
        System.out.println("bar1 after adding to clone: " + bar1.getInnerList());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
bar1 before cloning: [baz1, baz2, baz3]
clone: [baz1, baz2, baz3]
clone after adding to original: [baz1, baz2, baz3, baz4]
bar1 after adding to clone: [baz1, baz2, baz3, baz4, cloneBaz1]
```

Also, if you had added to the HashMap other object than String, you could see, that shallow copy works there too - the original and cloned map contain shared objects and therefore contents of both maps may change:

```
public class Test implements Cloneable {
    private String foo;

// getter/setter/toString ...

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<String, Test> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("a1", new Test("a1"));
        map.put("a2", new Test("a2"));
        map.put("a3", new Test("a3"));

        System.out.println("map before cloning: " + map);

        HashMap<String, Test> cmap = (HashMap<String, Test>) map.clone();

        System.out.println("clone: " + cmap);

        map.put("b1", new Test("b1"));
        System.out.println("clone after adding to original: " + cmap);

        cmap.put("c1", new Test("c1"));
        System.out.println("original after adding to clone: " + map);

        map.get("a1").setFoo("new a1");
        System.out.println("clone after modifying object inside original: " + cmap);

        cmap.get("a2").setFoo("cloned a2");
        System.out.println("original after modifying the clone: " + map);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
map before cloning: {a1=->a1, a2=->a2, a3=->a3}
clone: {a1=->a1, a2=->a2, a3=->a3}
clone after adding to original: {a1=->a1, a2=->a2, a3=->a3}
original after adding to clone: {a1=->a1, a2=->a2, a3=->a3, b1=->b1}
clone after modifying object inside original: {a1=->new a1, a2=->a2, a3=->a3, c1=->c1}
original after modifying the clone: {a1=->new a1, a2=->cloned a2, a3=->a3, b1=->b1}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex,Well explained really appreciate.